# How can I link to a specific revision?

Tags: support, editing, hyperlinks

Sometimes I want to refer readers to a specific revision of a question. Can I accomplish this with a single link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Sure!](http://meta.askubuntu.com/revisions/1423/1)

You can get a link to [the revision list](http://meta.askubuntu.com/posts/1423/revisions) for a post that's been edited simply by clicking the "edited [time]..." link underneath it, and from there simply click or copy the link labeled "link" at the top of each revision in the list. This will produce a complete rendered copy of that revision.

Comment: check again! you might be surprised what you find on that revisions page...

Comment: @Jeff: nice....